# Delete/clear opened text file which is used by another process

Tags: powershell

I'm getting following exception:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I want to simply clear a log file that is opened via PowerShell. Like following:

```
$path = ...
Clear-Content $path -Force
```

How can I do this even if the file is opened? *Windows Editor* and *Notepad++* can do it while the file is opened by my log viewer, but I can't do it in PowerShell. How do the editors do this? Can I somehow achieve this with PowerShell as well?

I also tried `Set-Content` to clear the content of the file with the same result.

**EDIT - Setup**

- my program writes to the log file (without problems, always, even if the log viewer is opened)
- I use glogg as log viewer (http://glogg.bonnefon.org/)
- If glogg is opened, the Powershell script fails
- I can reliably reproduce this and can see, that Notepad++ and the Windows Editor can overwrite the files content easily and always (as well as my app is still able to write to the log file of course), and glogg immediately displays the new log file content

**EDIT 2: ProcMon data**

*Case 1 - Glogg is opened and powershell fails*

```
11:11:12,1441593    powershell.exe  10304   QueryOpen   D:\VW_LOG.txt   SUCCESS CreationTime: 16.10.2014 09:59:18, LastAccessTime: 16.10.2014 10:13:51, LastWriteTime: 13.10.2017 10:22:07, ChangeTime: 13.10.2017 10:22:07, AllocationSize: 28.672, EndOfFile: 26.451, FileAttributes: A
11:11:12,1442828    powershell.exe  10304   CreateFile  D:\VW_LOG.txt   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Write, AllocationSize: n/a
```

*Case 2 - Glogg is closed and powershell succeeds*

```
11:12:48,9053637    powershell.exe  10304   QueryOpen   D:\VW_LOG.txt   SUCCESS CreationTime: 16.10.2014 09:59:18, LastAccessTime: 16.10.2014 10:13:51, LastWriteTime: 13.10.2017 10:22:07, ChangeTime: 13.10.2017 10:22:07, AllocationSize: 28.672, EndOfFile: 26.451, FileAttributes: A
11:12:48,9055053    powershell.exe  10304   CreateFile  D:\VW_LOG.txt   SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
11:12:48,9055581    powershell.exe  10304   QuerySecurityFile   D:\VW_LOG.txt   SUCCESS Information: Attribute
11:12:48,9055808    powershell.exe  10304   SetAllocationInformationFile    D:\VW_LOG.txt   SUCCESS AllocationSize: 0
11:12:48,9058881    powershell.exe  10304   CloseFile   D:\VW_LOG.txt   SUCCESS
```

**EDIT 3 - working alternative solution**

I call following in my powershell script and it works flawless:

```
ExecuteSimpleBatch "clear_file.bat" $path

function ExecuteSimpleBatch($file, $par)
{
    $fileName = Split-Path $file -leaf
    $fileFolder = Split-Path $file -parent

    Start-Process "cmd" -ArgumentList '/c', $file, $par -WorkingDirectory $fileFolder -WindowStyle hidden
}
```

Content of "clear_file.bat":

```
break > %1
```

Comment: You can't. Windows Editor and Notepad++ can't either so I assume you've drawn a wrong conclusion somewhere. If you are a bit familiar with procmon, you could have it run and monitor all file activity while performing you're actions in both Powershell/Notepad++ and draw conclusions from there.

Comment: I made an edit, you can simply reproduce this with any log file and will see that this happens. Somehow the editors overwrite the file although it's opened by the log viewer (it's a viewer anyways, the log file can be written by my app and by the editors, just not by powershell)

Comment: I've opened glogg and set it to follow testfile1.txt. Following works in powershell without issues `Clear-Content c:\temp\testfile1.txt -Force`

Comment: Can you download procmon from sysinternals and log (filter) your powershell attempt?

Comment: What I get and is relevant is following I believe: `SHARING VIOLATION` with `Operation: CreateFile` and `Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes`

Comment: I also added the procmon result for a successful vs a failing script execution to my post...

Comment: The sharing violation is your issue for sure. Can you share a log where you: stop everything. Start procmon and filter on D:\VW_LOG.txt. Start your app, glog, notepad++ and powershell and try to clear the file.

Comment: Will this help? Seems like powershell can't delete the file. I added a new edit that shows a working alternative solution, why does this one work but not the original powershell solution? A batch script can clear the content of the file... And I even run my scripts as admin always...

Comment: Powershell isn't trying to delete the file but there's a conflict in parameters with other programs opening the file. [You cannot request an access mode that conflicts with the sharing mode that is specified by the dwShareMode parameter in an open request that already has an open handle.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: My advice still is to get a look at the creation flags of the other programs by using procmon. Alternatively, you could try procexp to get the access flags but that depends on the program having the handle still open or not.

Comment: If I understand the already existing infos correctly, `Clear-Content` creates a new file that will replace the current file (because ProcMon is logging a `CreateFile` log entry). So this will never work if the file is opened, even if only for reading (as it is in my case). The batch command does not do this (it does not create a file), it just writes into the existing file, that's why it's working. Isn't this correct?

Comment: `CreateFile` `[Creates or opens a file or I/O device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx). Depending on the flags passed to the function, you can get sharing violations. Can you share a procmon trace using your various options? Perhaps like that, we can work it out.

Comment: Actually I just found a solution: `"" | Out-File $path -NoNewline -Encoding ASCII` this will work just fine... I still don't know what you are looking for, it must be the `Clear-Content` call that does request flags it does not need to clear the file (as all alternative methods work flawless). It's not important which flags, as I can't define them for `Clear-Content`, can I? I must use an alternative solution anyways (like `Out-file`) in my use case

Comment: you can post an answer and mark it solved. All I was after was a procmon trace. You can't change what gets passed to the CreateFile function but it would have served as verification of the theory. We might have worked from there to found a solution ;)

Comment: Still thanks for all the help, your suggestion with `ProcMon` helped me solving the issue

Answer (score 2):

*Finally I found a working solution:*

Instead of

```
Clear-Content $path
```

it's possible to use

```
"" | Out-File $path -NoNewline -Encoding ASCII
```

**Why**

Seems like `Clear-Content` is creating a new file and replaces the old one with it, while `Out-File` tries to write into an existing file (so opened read handles do not effect this)